# spirocerca lupi in dog

Tags: dogs, health, diseases

My dog has been diagnosed with spirocerca lupi. The parasite has reached his stomach as it has been in his system for a long time unfortunately I only found the issue through a general scan.

Anyway the vet has said there is no cure for it and it can only be managed. Has anyone had this in their dogs before? Please help urgently.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we can't offer better advice than your vet. However, if you feel unsatisfied with your dog's diagnosis and care plan, you can always get a second opinion elsewhere by trying a different vet.

Good luck, sir.

Answer (score -1):

My dog has just been diagnosed and will start medication today.  Do some research, you will find that there is medication available.  If I were you, I would get a second opinion from a more experienced vet.

Comment: What is the medication?

Comment: Please be more specific with your answers(as in this information could be helpful for OP and future users), if it's gonna be this broad it would serve better as a comment.